# Some SQLite tables can not be created, but others (using the same approach) can

Tags: database, sqlite, electron

I am making an Electron application, which uses an SQLite Database. Inside of the app's directory, I have a folder named **db** and as a child, another one - **seeder**. In that **seeder** directory there are a bunch of **.sql** files, needed for creating the db architecture and seeding the database with information needed:

```
Electron App/
    |---main.js
    |---index.html
    |---node_modules
    |---package.json
    |---db/
        |---seed.js
        |---seeder/
            |---bunch of .sql files
```

When I run **seed.js** it is supposed to get all filenames inside of **seeder/** and run every single one successively. The files are named as follows:

- 01.tables.sql
- 02.countries.sql
- 03.ekatte.sql - (this one contains all the villages and cities in Bulgaria)
- 04.programmes.sql
- 05.schedules.sql
- 06.subjects.sql

Everything works as expected, except one thing: **01.tables.sql** is supposed to create all the tables, and all other files contain `INSERT INTO` statements. Some of the tables are not created and when the Electron app tries to `INSERT INTO` them - sqlite returns an error: `no such table` (but only for **oblasti**, **programmes**, **schedules** and **subjects**).

Here are the contents of 01.table.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
    countryID integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT countries_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    countryName text NOT NULL,
    countryISO text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE grades (
    gradeID integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT grades_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    gradeValue integer NOT NULL,
    gradeStudent integer NOT NULL,
    gradeSchedule integer NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE oblasti (
    oblastID integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT oblasti_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    oblastName text NOT NULL,
    oblastCode text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE obshtini (
    obshtinaID integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT obshtini_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    obshtinaName text NOT NULL,
    obshtinaOblast integer NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE programmes (
    programmeID integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT programmes_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    programmeName text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE schedules (
    scheduleID integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT schedules_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    scheduleProgramme integer NOT NULL,
    scheduleSemester integer NOT NULL,
    scheduleSubject integer NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE selishta (
    selishteID integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT selishta_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    selishteName text NOT NULL,
    selishteObshtina integer NOT NULL,
    selishteOblast integer NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE students (
    studentID integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT students_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    studentName text NOT NULL,
    studentFamily text NOT NULL,
    studentPicture blob NOT NULL,
    studentBirthplace integer,
    studentForeignCountry integer,
    studentForeignOblast text,
    studentForeignObshtina text,
    studentForeignSelishte text,
    studentEGN integer NOT NULL,
    studentAddress text NOT NULL,
    studentPhone text NOT NULL,
    studentNationality integer NOT NULL,
    studentEduForm integer NOT NULL,
    studentOKS integer NOT NULL,
    studentSemester integer NOT NULL,
    studentClass integer NOT NULL,
    studentFakNomer integer NOT NULL,
    studentStatus integer NOT NULL,
    studentValid integer NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE subjects (
    subjectID integer NOT NULL CONSTRAINT subjects_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    subjectName text NOT NULL
);
```

and this is the part of **seed.js**, responsible for the actual seeding:

```
const db = new sqlite3.Database('db/database.db');
fs.readdir('db/seeder/', function(err, dir) {
    let fileList = new Array();
    $.each(dir, function(index, fileName){
        fileList.push(fileName);
    });
    fileList.sort();
    seedDB(fileList);
});
function seedDB(files){
    if(files.length > 0){
        let fileName = files.shift();
        fs.readFile('db/seeder/'+fileName, 'utf-8', function(err, data){
            db.serialize(function() {
                db.run(data);
            });
            seedDB(files);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The statements from `01.table.sql` work for me without any error message, the tables you mention are all created. What error messages do you get? Could the problem be in your `INSERT INTO` statements instead?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: schedules`
This is one of the errors I get in DevTools (other three are identical, just the table's name is different). These are the first three `INSERT INTO` statements for `schedules`: 
`    INSERT INTO schedules VALUES('1', '15', '1', '1');
    INSERT INTO schedules VALUES('2', '15', '1', '2');
    INSERT INTO schedules VALUES('3', '15', '1', '3');`
All other 1213 rows are identical - semicolons at the end and no empty rows.

Comment: Could the problem be with the seeding JavaScript? For example not handling the chaining as expected and therefore trying to execute `05.schedules.sql` before `01.tables.sql` or something. Seems pretty logical to me (the operations should be sequenced), but I am not a JS (neither NodeJS) expert at all. NB: I am using a jQuery module if that matters.